# How to fix version mismatch error when trying to create a Vue project?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to simply create a vue project using `vue create shop` but keep getting this error message:

```
Error: 

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.6.11 (/home/roy/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.10 (/home/roy/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-jscodeshift-adapter/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/package.json)

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.
```

I've tried `npm install vue-template-compiler --save-dev` but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

While typing this I discovered that `yarn global upgrade` worked in my case